# Get list of all modules using code in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.4

I am working on creating a base module for all other modules under one namespace.

I want to show a list of all modules (with their version and their status as enabled or disabled).

I have injected dependency of **`\Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleListInterface`** in my block file, but I am not getting the module in the list if I disable it.

I have tried **getAll()** and **getNames()** functions. No function is returning disabled module names in the list.

Previously it was possible to get the list of all modules because there was a section in admin panel (Advanced), where all modules were listed with respective module output.

Kindly help me to get the list of all modules.

Comment: How to find out which Magento module is customize/extended in Magento 2?

Comment: I think you need to ask a new question instead of commenting here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some study of Magento core modules, I checked the source, from where the following command is executed:

```
php bin/magento module:status
```

I found that Magento is using **`\Magento\Framework\Module\FullModuleList`** class to get the list of enabled and disabled modules.

Based on Magento's implementation, I have implemented my code in the following way:

```
<?php
namespace Mohit\Base\Block;

class Modules extends \Parent\Class
{
    protected $fullModuleList;

    public function __construct(
        \Other\Dependenciy\Classes,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\FullModuleList $fullModuleList
    ) {

        $this->fullModuleList = $fullModuleList;
    }

    public function modulesList()
    {
        ...
        $allModules = $this->fullModuleList->getAll();
        ...
    }
}
```

Also, tons of thanks to @sanne, who helped me to go in the right direction.

Comment: If we want to get a list of modules which exists in app/code directory, then what should I do ??

Answer (score 4):

A shot in the dark here, but maybe you could look how the terminal function bin/magento module:status works and copy that somehow? Because that shows all modules and the statuses? No idea how though.

Comment: Thanks, @sanne for the answer. I had been checking the same while you answered. Upvoted for the precious help.