# How to get list of third party modules programatically?

Tags: magento2

By using this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/235153/get-list-of-all-modules-using-code-in-magento-2) i am able to get all extensions list in Magento 2. But i want to get only Third Party extensions which are installed in `app/code` directory.

For example, there are 3 modules in `app/code` directory, then i only want to get list of these 3 modules.

Comment: there is no  such way available at Magento 2

Comment: @AmitBera i just want to get list of modules available in app/code directory. yash7690 provided a solution to fulfill my requirement. And thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create some Model file in your module as follow.

File: Model/CodeModules.php

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Model;

class CodeModules
{
    protected $moduleList;
    protected $moduleReader;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleList $moduleList,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader $moduleReader
    ) {
        $this->moduleList = $moduleList;
        $this->moduleReader = $moduleReader;
    }

    public function getCustomModules()
    {
        $result = [];

        $modules = $this->moduleList->getNames();
        foreach ($modules as $_module) {
            $dir = $this->moduleReader->getModuleDir(null, $_module);
            if(strpos($dir, 'app/code') !== false)
            {
                $result[] = $_module;
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Now call this function getCustomModules() wherever needed and you will get your expected result.

Comment: a module does exits at app/code folder not means it is 3rd party.Suppose, you have clone Magento 2 from GitHub repo then  Magento own module exits at `app/code/` folder. That is means  Magento own module are  3 party module

Comment: Some time composer also add third party module in vendor folder