# How to find out which Magento module is customize/extended in Magento EE 2.3.x?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, module, magento-core

**How to find out which Magento module is customize/extended in Magento EE 2.3.x ?**

Is there any CLI? or any other way to get this done?

Please reply as soon as possible.

Comment: Have you get custom module list ?

Comment: @Msquare Not yet bro, any idea?

Comment: i can helps you to get all third party module list .

Comment: @Msquare thanks then share it, the proper way of approach.

Answer (score 0):

> Add this code in your file where you want to get.

```
protected $moduleList;
protected $moduleReader;

public function __construct(
    .................................................
    \Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleList $moduleList,
    \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader $moduleReader,
    .................................................
) {
    .................................................
    $this->moduleList = $moduleList;
    $this->moduleReader = $moduleReader;
    .................................................
}
```

> now you can add this code in your custom function or execute() function

```
$result = [];

$modules = $this->moduleList->getNames();
foreach ($modules as $_module) {
    $dir = $this->moduleReader->getModuleDir(null, $_module);
    if(strpos($dir, 'app/code') !== false)
    {
        $result[] = $_module;
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
exit();
```

[Click here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261546/how-to-get-list-of-third-party-modules-programatically) for Reference link

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: Thanks for reply let me check!

Comment: please inform me it's helps you ?

Comment: No, it's not as per my requirements, by the way, thanks for your help. [ I want to find out Magento EE 2.3.x module which is customized/modified]